# Is Floating Point Texture Support Enabled in Mesa?

Tags: drivers, opengl, mesa

I am attempting to play a game through CrossOver for Linux.  However, I get a warning that floating-point textures isn't supported in OpenGL.  I recently found that this was due to a legal issue that has since been resolved.

Is there a way to enable floating-point texture support in the Mesa driver from the Ubuntu repositories?  Or am I required to compile an updated driver with the needed features enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so:

Install the latest drivers from [oibaf/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to check for the floating-point textures:

```
glxinfo | grep -i texture_float
```

If you get some output, you may assume that it is present.